# I am using Notification Service Extension but I am unable to get the image in the notification, How could I get the image in the Notification Center?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, notifications

I am using pusher app with development profile to get the Rich Push Notification with the image attached at the right side of Notification Center on iOS but I am unable to get the image on the notification whereas I could see the title, subtitle and body in the Push. Would there be any additional code that I will need to do in the Notification Service Extension?

```
{"aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Introduction To Notification",
            "subtitle" : "Session 707",
            "body" : "New Notification Look Amazing"
        },
       "sound" : "default",
        "category" : "message",
        "badge" : 1,
        "mutable-content": 1
    },
    "attachment-url": "https://i.imgur.com/t4WGJQx.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to download the image by yourself and call the completion handler after download completes.

Your 'notification extension' must have a viewController where you might have added your UI in storyboard named 'mainInterface.storyBoard'. So in your viewcontroller class let's say NotificationViewController, it needs to implement protocol: UNNotificationContentExtension,  and then delegate method you can implement as:

```
class NotificationViewController: UIViewController, UNNotificationContentExtension {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any required interface initialization here.
}

func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
    if let urlString = notification.request.content.userInfo["attachment-url"] as! String? {
        if let imageURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: imageURL) {
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
            }    
        }
    }  
  }
}
```

Here the image view is the outlet for image view that is added in your view controller.

P.S. You need to import frameworks as:

```
import UserNotifications
import UserNotificationsUI
```

You can refer custom notification tutorial [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-creating-custom-notification-interfaces--cms-27251)

Comment: Thank you!!! Nowhere in all the guides and documentation have I been able to find an example like this. It's working now.